# Count,Count How many legs?

Tags: logical-deduction

You walk into your room to your bed. On the bed there are 5 monkeys, 2 cats and 3 dogs. So how many legs are total on the floor?

Comment: Whatsapp riddles, eh?

Comment: Definitely yeah @Sid

Answer (score 3):

As

> all the animals are on the bed, the only legs touching the ground are the 4 legs of the bed and your 2. Makes 6 in total.